# InvalidCastException - Cannot cast string to custom object even with operators

Tags: c#, nhibernate, operators, castle-activerecord

I am probably trying to do something that isn't possible. I am working with Castle.ActiveRecord / Nhibernate. I have been happy so far, but one thing I have always wanted to able to so is have something like:

```
[Property(ColumnType = "StringClob")]
public IDictionary<string, string> MetaData { get; set; }
```

This, for obvious reasons, this isn't possible at the moment. I started playing around with things to make this work and have come down to the following.

I have created a custom class that extends Dictionary

```
public class SerializableDictionary<TK, TV> : Dictionary<TK, TV>
{
    public static explicit operator SerializableDictionary<TK, TV>(System.String serialized)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SerializableDictionary<TK, TV>>(serialized);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

And in my ActiveRecord model I have this:

```
[Property(ColumnType = "StringClob")]
public SerializableDictionary<string, string> MetaData { get; set; }
```

This works extremely well when I save the data. It gets serialized nicely and stores as a string. When I try to load a model though, I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyNamespace.SerializableDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.
```

I have looked as deep as possible (using dotPeek) into where this is happening. The stack trace led me to:

```
NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.AccessOptimizer.SetPropertyValues(Object target, Object[] values)
```

I am at a complete loss. I have scoured google to see if what I am trying to do is even possible. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious, does changing it to an `implicit` operator help?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: NHibernate actually generates IL code on the fly for setting properties quickly and avoiding reflection overhead.  Unfortunately, the IL code it generates doesn't think to call implicit conversion operators.

Comment: Does that mean that something like this isn't possible?

Comment: Umm, I *think* you can.  The question is how much junk you have to rewrite.  Unfortunately, I don't have time to really dig into this right now.  However, I did write a [blog post](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/12/21/using-enum-types-with-postgresql-and-castle-activerecord/) a while back on mapping C# Enums to PostgreSQL ENUMs.  It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That really helped. I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out after being pointed in the right direction by [Mike Christensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392044/mike-christensen)
in the comments.

All of this code is probably overkill, and somethings are probably inefficient because I was doing it as fast as I could. But here it is...

I started with the same extend class as in the question (I modified it a little, because I'm still not sure how to implement the generics).

```
public class SerializableDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public static explicit operator SerializableDictionary(String serialized)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SerializableDictionary>(serialized);
    }

    public static explicit operator String(SerializableDictionary dict)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

I next had to create a custom SqlType for NHibernate. This class had to implement IUserType, which came with a bunch methods that had to be implemented (I'm not sure I implemented these the best way possible). This class now allows NHibernate to use the NullSafeSet to set the model property with the string from the database. There I was able to do the deserialization.

```
public class SerializableDictionaryType : IUserType
{
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return x != null && x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        string dbString = (string) NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names);
        SerializableDictionary dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SerializableDictionary>(dbString);
        return dict;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            return;
        }
        value = value.ToString();
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index);
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        SerializableDictionary newDict = new SerializableDictionary();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in (SerializableDictionary)value)
        {
            newDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        return newDict;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SerializableDictionary>(cached.ToString());
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            SqlType[] types = new SqlType[1];
            types[0] = new SqlType(DbType.String);
            return types;
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof (SerializableDictionary); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Then on the model itself I had to put the following:

```
[Property(ColumnType = "MyNamespace.SerializableDictionaryType, MyNamespace")]
public SerializableDictionary UserData { get; set; }
```

This ColumnType refers to the custom type mapper that I created. If you notice I had to use the full namespace and class along with the assembly it's located in.

With all of this setup it works like a charm. I'm planning on optimizing things to make it look nicer and would still like to find a way to deal with generics instead of being stuck with:

```
<string, object>
```

I'll update the answer with anything I find.